# Security Group only showing outbound rules

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-security-group

I have a Postgres RDS instance set-up and configured within a VPC with subnets and security groups.

The issue is that the instance doesn't seem to be allowing inbound connections. In the AWS RDS console under connect it displays the security group and shows the outbound rule. However, it doesn't show the inbound rule which is odd as on a MySQL instance I have set-up with the same security group, both rules are showing.

Is there a way to specify both inbound and outbound rules for a security group on an instance? I can't seem to find where this is specified.

Comment: Are both the instances with a VPC security group?, In VPC security group you can specify both inbound and outbount however anything that is allowed in is automatically allowed to go out in security groups, refer [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html) for more

Comment: Yes I've double checked and both within the same group. I've just figured it out though - I needed to add an inbound rule to the security group for the postgres port 5432. It only had one for mysql

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an inbound rule for postgres db port in security group.

edit: blountdj findings in the comment above is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue, but for a terraform-created MySQL RDS instance. The issue is with the security group port configuration. In my case, I fat-fingered `3066` as the security group port, instead of the correct `3306` port.

If you encounter an issue in the future with the Inbound security group rules not showing up in the AWS RDS instance, **verify the Security Group port configuration is the same as the expected port configuration.** If one doesn't exist, create an Inbound security group rule on the attached security group and make sure the security group rule aligns with the port of your database.